# get values from each itme in xml code with python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I have this xml code:

```
<item>
    <field var="name" type="text-single"><value>jhon</value></field>
    <field var="subject" type="text-single"><value>Test SERVER</value></field>
    <field var="num_users" type="text-single"><value>11</value></field>
    <field var="num_max_users" type="text-single"><value>25</value></field>
    <field var="is_password_protected" type="boolean"><value>false</value></field>
    <field var="is_member_only" type="boolean"><value>false</value></field>
    <field var="language" type="text-single"><value>es</value></field>
    <field var="location-type" type="list-single"><value>worldwide</value></field>
    <field var="location" type="text-single"><value /></field>
    <field var="jid" type="jid-single"><value>jhon@example.com</value></field>
</item>

<item>
    <field var="name" type="text-single"><value>jhon</value></field>
    <field var="subject" type="text-single"><value>Test SERVER</value></field>
    <field var="num_users" type="text-single"><value>11</value></field>
    <field var="num_max_users" type="text-single"><value>25</value></field>
    <field var="is_password_protected" type="boolean"><value>false</value></field>
    <field var="is_member_only" type="boolean"><value>false</value></field>
    <field var="language" type="text-single"><value>es</value></field>
    <field var="location-type" type="list-single"><value>worldwide</value></field>
    <field var="location" type="text-single"><value /></field>
    <field var="jid" type="jid-single"><value>jhon@example.com</value></field>
</item>
```

How i can get `values` for each `item` with `var` for each `value` with python?

---

example output:

Name: Jhone

Num_users: 11

is_password_protected: false

---

hope someone help me. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @khajvah i try with `BeautifulSoup` but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried to solve this problem with and post the problem you had with it. As for the problem, try [The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and come back when you have an actual problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please check the below tutorial,
https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('your.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root.findall('field'):  
   name = item.find('value').text
```

please try the above sample and let me know your feedback

```
test.xml

    <item>
        <field var="name" type="text-single"><value>jhon</value></field>
        <field var="subject" type="text-single"><value>Test SERVER</value></field>
        <field var="num_users" type="text-single"><value>11</value></field>
        <field var="num_max_users" type="text-single"><value>25</value></field>
        <field var="is_password_protected" type="boolean"><value>false</value></field>
        <field var="is_member_only" type="boolean"><value>false</value></field>
        <field var="language" type="text-single"><value>es</value></field>
        <field var="location-type" type="list-single"><value>worldwide</value></field>
        <field var="location" type="text-single"><value /></field>
        <field var="jid" type="jid-single"><value>jhon@example.com</value></field>
    </item>

        In [1]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

        In [2]: tree = ET.parse('test.xml')

        In [3]: root = tree.getroot()

        In [4]: for item in root.findall('field'):
            name = item.find('value').text
            print name
           ...:     
        jhon
        Test SERVER
        11
        25
        false
        false
        es
        worldwide
        None
        jhon@example.com
```

Comment: code working but No output!!

Comment: try again, i have changed something in code.

Comment: same thing. No output. Please save the above code as xml code and try your code if its work or not

Comment: please chek the above, i have posted my sample code & output

Comment: Great! it works now. but what if just i need to get `value` of `var=num_users` ?

Comment: @icoder Do it yourself. This is not a free source of programmers. The guy already gave you more than he should have.

Comment: Ok thank you @Muthuvel